# golangで2D arrayの一部を素早くコピーする方法

Tags: go

golangを使って、2D array(もしくは２D slice型)の一部を早くコピーする方法を探しています。

先にサンプルコードを書いて、その後詳しく質問させていただきます。

```golang
package main

import "strconv"

func CreateNewMatrix(Nrow int, Ncol int) [][]int {
    ///create Nrow x Ncol matrix
    tmpImg := make([][]int, Nrow) 
    for i := range tmpImg { 
        tmpImg[i] = make([]int, Ncol) 
    }   
    return tmpImg
}

func main() {

    MaxRowSize := 1000
    MaxColSize := 1000

    M := CreateNewMatrix(MaxRowSize, MaxColSize)

    for iy:=0; iy<MaxRowSize; iy++  {
        for ix:=0; ix<MaxColSize; ix++ {
            M[iy][ix] = iy+ix
        }
    }

    smallM_Size := 25;
    tmp := ""
    smallM := map[int]string{}  //便宜上、mapを使っています。
    idx := 0
    for iy:=0; iy<MaxRowSize; iy += smallM_Size  {
        for ix:=0; ix<MaxColSize; ix += smallM_Size {
            tmp = ""

            for sy:=0; sy<smallM_Size; sy++ {
                for sx:=0; sx<smallM_Size; sx++ {
                    tmp += strconv.Itoa(M[iy+sy][ix+sx])
                    tmp += ":"
                }
            }
            smallM[idx] = tmp
            idx++
        }
    }
}
```

上記で行っていることは、まず1000x1000の行列（"M"としています）を作成します。
その次に各エレメントに新規の情報(ここでは、iy+ix)を加えています。
この行列Mを用いて、その一部から25x25の小さな行列(map型のsmallMとします)の内容をコピーしています。便宜上このコピーしたsmallMの情報は、":"で区切られたstring型で保持しています。

ここでは、smallMを作成するときに、各エレメントづつコピーしていますが、
より早くコピーする方法があるかどうかを知りたいです。

実際にはこの動作をより大きなサイズの行列Mに対し、より多くのsmallMを作成する必要があります。
何とかこのプロセスにかかる時間を削減したいと考えています。

少し試したことは、M[iy][1:25]などによる行列へのアクセス方法は知っていますが、
これをsmallMに直接移すことを試みましたが、どうやらできないようです。

ただ単にコピーがしたいだけですので、早く行う方法・アルゴリズムなどを知っていれば、ご教授をお願いしたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: コピーでなければダメですか? スライスを用いてサブビューを作成するほうが、処理速度は速くなると考えられますが。

Comment: ありがとうございます。コピーとサブビューのアルゴリズム的な思考でどれほどの計算速度の差が出てくるのか、未だに完全には理解していませんが、一度試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

前提条件として以下の様に設定されているとします。

- 行列 M の行数・列数は smallM のそれの整数倍

その上で、smallM を matrix(2次元スライス)のスライス(3次元スライス)にしてみてはどうでしょうか。以下はそのコードで、`package main` 〜 `CreateNewMatrix` 関数までは省いてあります。

**copy_matrix.go**

```golang
func main() {

    MaxRowSize := 1000
    MaxColSize := 1000

    M := CreateNewMatrix(MaxRowSize, MaxColSize)

    for iy := 0; iy < MaxRowSize; iy++ {
        for ix := 0; ix < MaxColSize; ix++ {
            M[iy][ix] = iy + ix
        }
    }

    smallM_Size := 25
    ny, nx := MaxRowSize/smallM_Size, MaxColSize/smallM_Size
    smallM := make([][][]int, nx*ny)
    for iy := 0; iy < ny; iy++ {
        for ix := 0; ix < nx; ix++ {
            nth := iy*nx + ix
            smallM[nth] = CreateNewMatrix(smallM_Size, smallM_Size)
            for i := 0; i < smallM_Size; i++ {
                copy(smallM[nth][i], M[smallM_Size*iy+i][(smallM_Size*ix):(smallM_Size*(ix+1))])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分で作っていておいてなんなんですが、「smallM[nth] = CreateNewMatrix」のような使い方もできるんですね。
また、3Dsliceは試してはみたのですが、すべて「for loop」を使っていたので、非常に計算が遅かったので、ここで質問させていただきました。
確かにArgus様の方法ですと、私のコードより約20倍早くなっています。大変勉強になりました。今後ともよろしくお願いします。